# Simple Query Help Required

Tags: join, query

I have this table

```
uid  |  rid
-----------
1    |    4
1    |   13
2    |    4
3    |   13
```

I want my query to return the uid where it has rid = 13 AND does not have rid = 4 so the result would be 13

So far I have

```
SELECT distinct uid
FROM test
WHERE 
ur.rid <> 4 
AND ur.rid = 13
```

but of course this is returning 1 and 3

What am I missing from my query to get only 3?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is called an antisemijoin or just antijoin. Since both wanted and not wanted conditions are matched to the same table, we may call it a self antijoin.

It can be done with either a `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` or a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT wanted.uid
FROM test AS wanted
WHERE wanted.rid = 13
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM test AS notwanted
        WHERE notwanted.uid = wanted.uid
          AND notwanted.rid = 4
      ) ;
```